# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 alsa & jackd Headphone Jack Configuration

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, alsa

My end goal is to do headless remote audio streaming with jacktrip on some older Pi 2 boards using the built-in headphone jack (I know the quality of it is lacking but I don't really care).

To narrow the scope of my issue, I am trying to get jackd (jack2/jack2-dbus) working with alsa on a Pi to just play through the headphone jack. Here is the issue that I am currently running into and I have not been able to find the solution online.

When I do a `jackd -dalsa -r44100 -p512 -n2 -P`, it fails to connect to alsa. Specifcally this line is what I suspect is the issue

```
ALSA: poll time out, polled for 17413109 usecs
```

Here is the full log

```
> jackd -dalsa -r44100 -p512 -n2 -P
jackdmp 1.9.12
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2017 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|-|512|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 512 frames (11.6 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
jackd -dalsa -r44100 -p512 -n2 -P
ALSA: poll time out, polled for 17413109 usecs
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, stopping...
^CJack main caught signal 2
Released audio card Audio0
audio_reservation_finish
```

Here is a list of my hardware devices

```
> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

OS Version ([Raspberry Pi OS with desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/))

```
> cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Alsa config file

```
> cat /etc/asound.conf 
pcm.!default {
     type hw
     card 0
}

ctl.!default {
     type hw
     card 0
}
```

In trying to do some additional troubleshooting, I have tried jackd with a dummy interface and everything works

```
> jackd -ddummy -r44100 -p512 -P
jackdmp 1.9.12
...
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
```

A decent number of articles online say that jack and pulseaudio cause issues if running together. I have uninstalled pulseaudio for the above

```
sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I have tried configuring it through qjackctl and jack_control (jack2-dbus) and run into similar errors with alsa timing out.

Does anyone know how to get jackd and alsa to work correctly on the Pi 2?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... noob here...
But dont you have to specify your selected output?

I am using the following on an OrangePi:
/usr/bin/jackd --realtime -P70 --silent -d alsa -P hw:1 -p 128 -n 2 -r 44100

Where hw:1 refers to my USB sound card:
orangepi@orangepipc:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Codec          ]: H3_Audio_Codec - H3 Audio Codec
H3 Audio Codec
1 [AUDI▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒   ]: USB-Audio - USB AUDIÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
BurrBrown from Texas Instruments USB AUDIÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ at usb-1c1c400.usb-1,
2 [sun9ihdmi      ]: sun9i-hdmi - sun9i-hdmi
sun9i-hdmi